# if this function $f$ is homeomorphic then have $V=R^n$

Tags: analysis

Let Open sets $V\subset R^n,n\in N^{+}$, and the function $f:V\to R^n$ is homeomorphic,(Now add condition:)and $f$ is uniformly continuous.

show that
$$V=R^n$$

My idea: since
$$V\subset R^n$$
so we must prove
$$R^n\subset V$$
because the function $f:V\to R^n$ is homeomorphic,I can't use this condition.

Comment: What about $V=(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)\subseteq \mathbb R^1$ and $f(x)=\arctan x$?

Comment: Oh,Nice +1.Hello,if $f$ add condition, such as $f$ is uniformly continuously?

Comment: If $f$ is uniformly continuous, you can show that it extends (uniquely) to a continuous map $f : \overline{V}\to \Bbb{R}^n$. Maybe this could help you.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: There is something wrong with your example. The function $f$  doesn't map $V$ onto ${\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in \partial V$. Then there exists a sequence  $a_k\in V$ with $a_k\to a$. Consider the sequence  $b_k:=f(a_k)$. As $f$ is uniformly continuous it maps Cauchy sequences to bounded sequences. Thus $b_k$ is bounded and has a convergent subsequence $b_{k_\nu}\to b$. Then $a_{k_\nu}=f^{-1}(b_{k_\nu})\to f^{-1}(b)\in V$, hence $a=f^{-1}(b)\in V$. This shows that $\partial V\subseteq V$. Since $\mathbb R^n$ is connected, this implies $V=\mathbb R^n$ (or $V=\emptyset$, but that is excluded).